# Использование японских символов

Tags: python, unicode

Получаю ошибку: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position..

```
print('アイウエオァィゥェォカキク')
```

Есть специальный метод, чтобы конвертировать в unicod? Если есть способ использовать без конвертации, как есть, то тоже подойдет.

'''Пример программы, которая в качестве алфавита и ключа должна принять иероглифы. Код скопировать и вставить в ответ на codewars: [https://www.codewars.com/kata/52d1bd3694d26f8d6e0000d3/train/python'''](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52d1bd3694d26f8d6e0000d3/train/python%27%27%27)

```
class VigenereCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key, alphabet):
        key *= len(alphabet) // len(key) + 1
        self.key = key
        self.alphabet = alphabet

    def encode(self, text):
        result = ''
        text = list(text)
        for i in range(len(text)):
            if text[i] in "/[!., ']/":
                result += text[i]
                continue
            if text[i] not in self.alphabet:
                return "".join(text)
            t = self.alphabet.index((text[i])) + self.alphabet.index(self.key[i])
            if t >= len(self.alphabet):
                t -= len(self.alphabet)
            result += self.alphabet[t]
        return result

    def decode(self, text):
        result = ''
        text = list(text)
        for i in range(len(text)):
            if text[i] in "/[!., ']/":
                result += text[i]
                continue
            if text[i] not in self.alphabet:
                return "".join(text)
            t = self.alphabet.index((text[i])) - self.alphabet.index(self.key[i])
            if t < 0:
                t += len(self.alphabet)
            result += self.alphabet[t]
        return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте поменять кодировку файла на utf-8, второй момент смените кодировку консоли:

```py
import os
os.system("chcp 936")
print(u'アイウエオァィゥェォカキク')
```

Можно кодировку менять не в скрипте в ввести в консоли `chcp 936`, а затем выполнить скрипт.

Использование в коде:

```py
a = "アイ" # какой-то возврат от программы

if a =="アイ": # обрабатываем дальше
    print("OK")
else:
    print("err")
```

Comment: Попробовал, получил ту же ошибку. Кодировка файла не подойдет, это для задачки с codewars, решение написал, но одна из проверок кидает в программу иероглифы. Нужно с ними прямо в решении задачи взаимодействовать. Есть еще идея?

Comment: @Sudo Trololo а возможно какой-нибудь воспроизводимый пример? Возможно не до конца понимаю проблему но в коде вроде все и так работает.. Как пример добавил в ответ.

Comment: Задачка с codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/52d1bd3694d26f8d6e0000d3/train/python
...
Свое решение разместил в шапке вопроса, для примера. Можете попробовать скопировать мой код и поместить в решение, проходит все проверки, кроме иероглифов.